# Не удается выложить верстку на pages.github.com

Tags: git, github-pages

следовал полностью  инструкции  https://pages.github.com/

Создал репо `John.github.io` получается такая ссылка `https://github.com/John/Jonh.github.io`
После, склонировал `git clone https://github.com/John/John.github.io` 
Далее, создал проект на основе всего и заиндексировал

```
   git add --all
   git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Затем, запушил `git push -u origin master`

перехожу `https://jonh.github.io`

```
    404
There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.
```

не уж-то я где-то ошибся?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходимо включить Github Pages в настройках репозитория

Github -> Your Repo -> Settings -> Github Pages -> master branch

в корне или в папке /docs должен лежать index.html

[image: Включение Github pages]